# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have used following code to click on number of links

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("Click on "+ linkelement.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
driver.navigate().to(Filtered_links[i]);
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.switchTo().window(homeWindow);
```

However i have used `thread.sleep()` method wherever page changed I still get the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: 
Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it `enter code  
here`was looked up
```

Any one have idea why....! :(

Comment: Is the href link getting opened in separate tab or new window? Also, does the HOME window has a locator like id or name ? Also check, in which page the `stale element exception is occurring`. Is it in the HomeWindow or newly opened window.

Comment: Each new link open in same window . and yes link where program stuck is working fine when i copy paste in new tab...As i open all link in same window hence error occurred on same page

Comment: instead of `Thread.sleep()` we can use `webDriverWait` method where we can wait for an element to be present on the newly loaded page. So, let me know if there is any similar element present on all the newly loaded pages, so that i can guide you with usage of `webDriverWait()` By using this approach, we can assure that `staleElementException` do not occur.

Comment: when i used driver.wait(2000) method instead of sleep() than it gives me below error: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 at AccessSpecificLink2.main(AccessSpecificLink2.java:65)

Comment: I am talking about Explicitwait where we will wait for an element to appear on the new page. We can use the `ExpectedConditions` class 
`webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 180);`  `webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(""))); `

Comment: homeWindow = driver.getWindowHandle().toString();
System.out.println("Click on each Filtered Links");
for(int i=0;i<Filtered_links.length;i++)
{
  if (Filtered_links[i] == null)
 {   //System.out.println("Null value encountered");  }
 else 
{  driver.wait(3000);
   System.out.println("Click on "+ linkelement.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
driver.navigate().to(Filtered_links[i]); 
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.switchTo().window(homeWindow);
 } }

Comment: in Filtered_links array i get all links of page by using below Filtered_links[i] = linkelement.get(i).getAttribute("href");
and than try to filter & click on specific links based on some string

Comment: can you share the website url if it is not confidential so that i can debug it further?

Comment: yeh sure, its http://www.sandhira.com, or may i have your mail address through which i can get u r more help .

Comment: You can send your queries to hemu216@gmail.com

Comment: However I caught that webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(""))) this method is used to wait till particular element present but i need to check that weather whole page i loaded or not ..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution for above

need to remove "System.out.println("Click on "+ linkelement.get(i).getAttribute("href"));" statement from code and its working fine .